# Why does using an encoding trick like Gödel numbers make a register machine universal?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, turing-completeness

Here the author describes the [Random Access Stored Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine) machine and the problem of indirect addressing.

The author [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine#Elgot-Robinson_.281964.29_and_the_problem_of_the_RASP_without_indirect_addressing):

> But this does not solve the problem (unless one resorts to Gödel numbers). What is necessary is a method to fetch the address of a program instruction that lies (far) "beyond/above" the upper bound of the finite state machine's instruction register and TABLE.
>
> However, with only 4 registers, this machine has not nearly big enough to build a RASP that can execute the multiply algorithm as a program. No matter how big we build our finite state machine there will always be a program (including its parameters) which is larger. So by definition the bounded program machine that does not use unbounded encoding tricks such as Gödel numbers cannot be universal.
>
> problem of the RASP without indirect addressing

Steven Wolfram [weighs in saying](https://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1121a-text):

> The results of page 100 suggest that with 2 registers and up to 8 instructions no universal register machines (URMs) exist.

My question is: **Why does using an encoding trick like [Gödel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) make a register machine universal?**